# Accessing Nested Array in a D3 variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

This one has got to be easy but I can't for the life of me figure out why it's not working.

I've got some D3 code to plot some circles. I've nested arrays of six numbers inside a single variable (called 'dataset'). I'm trying to access those values to use a a y-value for the circle.

```
    var width = 600;
    var height = 400;


    var dataset = [[16.58, 17.90, 17.11, 17.37, 13.68, 13.95], [20.26,1 3.40, 18.63, 19.28, 20,92, 18.95], [16.32, 23.16, 21.05, 28.16, 23.68, 23.42], [31.32, 30.80, 29.37, 28.16, 32.37, 27.63], [41.32, 39.74, 29.37, 35.00, 35.53, 30.00], [25.83, 38.27, 43.33, 45.83, 44.17, 41.25]];


    var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

        svg.selectAll("circle")
           .data(dataset)
           .enter()
           .append("circle")
           .attr("cx", function(d, i) {
                return i * 100 + 50;
           })
           .attr("cy", function(d, i) {
             for (var j = 0; j<6; j++){
                //console.log(i,j);
                return d[i][j];   //THIS IS WHERE I'M FAILING
            }
           })
           .attr("r", 15);
```

So the x values are just 100 px intervals (I basically want each set in its own column). The y value of each circle should then be the j'th term in the i'th array. So why doesn't d[i][j] return that?

I've got a console.log statement commented out. If I un-commennt that everything logs just as I would expect, but the double bracket notation is clearly not accessing the numbers. If I go straight to the console in the browser and type dataset[0][1], it returns '17.90', so why doesn't it work in this implementation?

So confused.

Thanks

Comment: [**This article**](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/) is a good read. Check it out.

Comment: Thanks jshanley. I actually spent a couple of hours trying to decipher that article. I should add that I'm not much of a coder but can fumble my way through the basics. I tried attaching my data as a function thinking that would solve it, but clearly I messed up the syntax if not something else. Also, even if I'm approaching this incorrectly, would like to know why my attempt doesn't work so I can better understand what's going on.

Comment: [**HERE**](http://jsbin.com/nubire/1/edit?js,output) is what it looks like you're trying to do. I've commented the sections relevant to the nested selection. Hope that helps.

Comment: The problem with your earlier code is you are using `return` in your for-loop, which will return on the first iteration rather than continuing through the loop. The attr "cy" function will only be run 6 times, since the dataset only has 6 items (each item being an array).

Comment: Thanks, particularly for the explanation on why it didn't work. Was unaware that 'return' would only apply on the first iteration through. Not necessarily intuitive, but now I know what I was doing wrong.