# Accessing multi-dimensional D3 nest() rollup keys and values

Tags: arrays, d3.js

I'm having a problem accessing data that I've nested in D3. I believe I've nested and rolled up the data correctly but subsequently I don't seem to be able to access the new key/value pairs I've created.

The original data is a JSON blob with each test, its date of completion, subject area and score. What I want to acheive is to plot a separate set of average score datapoints on a chart by day for each subject. I've used nest previously to get an overall daily score and have plotted this successfully with the scales referenced in the code below but a two level heirarchy is getting the better of me. When I log the new 'nestedData' object it looks correct to me (i.e. the expected values are all there and grouped as I would expect).

I've worked on a few different versions of this with no success. I'm wondering if I'm trying to do something nest isn't designed for or if it's simply that my array notation is wrong (quite possible!). The code below shows the basic framework I'm using. What I'm missing is a filter to select the appropriate subject and the correct way to then access the average daily score from the rollup.

```
    // Takes original data and nest by date and then subject and rolls up on count of work and mean score 

    var dataToNest = data;
          nestedData = d3.nest()
            .key(function(el) {return el.dateCompleted})
            .key(function(el) {return el.subject})
            .rollup(function(leaves) {
              return {"numberCompleted": leaves.length,
                      "averageScore": d3.mean(leaves, function(d) {return(d.score)})}
            })
            .entries(dataToNest);

   // Format date as JS object

            nestedData.forEach(function (el) {
               el.key = new Date(el.key);
             });

   // Sort by date    

             nestedData.sort(function (a,b) {
               return a.key - b.key;
             });

     // Code for scales etc not included  

      d3.select("svg")
        .selectAll("circle")
        .data(nestedData)
        .filter(/* Filter by subject */)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("class", "subject")
        .attr("r", 5)
        .attr("cy", function (d) {/* Get the average score for the selected subject */})
        .attr("cx", function(d) {return xScale(d.key)});
```

Some things I've tried:

For the filter I've attempted to select the value of the second key (the subject key) using various iterations of d.values.key === 'Algebra'

For the average score I've tried accessing using iterations of d.values.values.averageScore as well as a function that iterated through the index of the second array.

My strong suspicion is that this is a problem with my understanding of how arrays are structured and referenced in javascript. I've read all the related posts on this but they seem to be mostly about using nest() rather than accessing the values from within it.

**UPDATE**

Got my foot in the door with the following:

```
svg.selectAll('.circle-group')
.data(nestedSubjectData)
.enter().append('g')
.attr('class', 'circle-group')
.attr('transform', function(d, i) {
    return 'translate(' + xScale(d.key) + ',0)';
    })
.selectAll('circle')
.data(function(d) {return d.values;})
.enter().append('circle')
 .attr('class', function(d) {return d.key;})
 .attr('cx', 0)
 .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.values.averageScore; })
 .attr('r', 5);
```

This adds a circle for the averageScore datapoint in each of the arrays at the second level and applies a class that can be used to differentiate the subjects.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? From how you're using the data it doesn't look like you need the nesting.

Comment: Hi Lars. I'm trying to plot four things: an overall score by date (which I've done with a simple one-level nest) and then an overall score by date for each of three subjects (though obviously I'd like it to be flexible enough to handle more than three subjects. So ultimately I'd have four scatterplots on a single chart.

Comment: You're going to need [nested selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/) with your nested data then.

Comment: Thanks Lars. Useful article. In conjunction with the comments on this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25533540/accessing-nested-array-in-a-d3-variable?rq=1 - I think I've started to get my head around this!

Comment: Great, feel free to post an answer to help other people struggling with this.

Comment: Will do. I'm still trying to get a path to draw correctly between the points. Once I've got that up and running I'll post a complete answer.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Lars and a few related questions on SO I got to the bottom of this. The code is below. Having tried this out a few different ways I changed the nesting order to something more logical. Since date and score are used to set x/y coordinates it was easier to keep them at one level and to set the subject as the first level. This makes it easier to split out each series for styling and other series-level interaction (like just switching an entire subject on or off in the visualisation).

My chart now shows a point for each daily average score within each subject with a line between them. You can remove one or the other and it will still work fine.

I haven't included the data but it's a JSON doc. Similarly I haven't included all my scales or the svg creation.

```
// Nest data by subject and day and get average overall

var subjectDataToNest = data;
nestedSubjectData = d3.nest()
  .key(function(el) {return el.subject}) // Nest by subject first
  .key(function(el) {return el.dateAppeared}) // Within each subject array create an array for each day
  .sortKeys(d3.ascending) // Sort the daily arrays by date (but this doesn't work reliably)
  .rollup(function(leaves) {
    return {
            "averageScore" : d3.mean(leaves, function(d) {return(d.score)}) // Return the average score 
          }
  })
  .entries(subjectDataToNest);

// Draw circles for each subject and each 

svg.selectAll('.subject-group')
.data(nestedSubjectData)
.enter().append('g')
// Create a group to contain each circle and (eventually) the path
.attr('class', 'subject-group')
.attr("id", function(d) {return d.key;})
// Change the selection
.selectAll('circle')
// Change the data to return index of nested array
.data(function(d) {return d.values;})
.enter().append('circle')
// Convert string date (which is the key in the nested array) to object and apply scale
.attr('cx', function(d) {return xScale(new Date(d.key));})
.attr('cy', function(d) { return yScale(d.values.averageScore); })
.attr('r', 5);

 //Draw line

 // 1. d3.svg.line() line generator takes values and retuns x/y c-oords for each datapoint 

 var subjectPath = d3.svg.line()
   .x(function(d) {
     return xScale(new Date(d.key));})
   .y(function(d) {
     return yScale(d.values.averageScore);
     })

// 2. Select the subject group and append a path to each
 svg.selectAll(".subject-group")
   .data(nestedSubjectData)
   .append('path')
   .attr('class', 'subject-line')
   .attr("d", subjectPath)
   // Pass the second level of the nested array to subjectPath to generate x/y co-ords for the 
   .attr("d",function(d) {return subjectPath(d.values);});
```

Useful Reading:

[Nested Selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/)

[jshanley's nested selection JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/nubire/1/edit?js,output) - Relates to SO Question [Accessing Nested Array in a D3 variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25533540/accessing-nested-array-in-a-d3-variable?rq=1)

[Phoebe Bright's canonical D3 nest examples](http://bl.ocks.org/phoebebright/raw/3176159/)